# How to select new constructor in subquery in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm trying to select two list using hibernate.

```
SELECT new List(m.id, m.someField), (select new List(s.id, s.someAnotherField) from MyTable s WHERE s.id = :id) FROM MyTable m WHERE m.id=:id
```

But when I trying execute above query I get an exception like below:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode!
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.getDataType(ConstructorNode.java:123)
```

How can I select a few sublist in one query? What am I doing wrong in above example?

Comment: Both the queries have no relation with each other, why do you need subquery in the first place & such a result. You can execute it twice independently & get result list.

Comment: For me personally the best solution would be: select new List(value), new  List(value2) from myTable because I need a list of DTOs created on similar entities in joined query